# Python type as a string

Tags: python

I'm attempting to display a string that provides the type of a given variable.

When I try the following:

```
'This is a '+str(type(somevariable))
```

the output is `"This is a <type 'float'>"`, instead of `"This is a float"`.

How do I get the output I want?

Comment: This should work. What error message do you get?

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't tell us the problem.  Unexpected output?  Error message?  Elaborate.

Comment: Well, I guess it kind of works.  The output is `"This is a <type 'float'>"`.  I want it to be just `"This is a float"`.

Comment: @HarperLee: Please update your question with this information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
'This is a ' + type(somevariable).__name__
```

Answer (score 4):

```
somevariable.__class__.__name__
```

is one way.